# Cheap test for determining if mod_rewrite is on in htaccess?

Tags: mod-rewrite

This is a common gripe of mine.

I was curious if there is a cheap test to know if mod_rewrite is on?

Is there a directive that i can add to the htaccess file to determine if mod_rewrite is on?

Comment: Do you need to see if mod_rewrite is installed on the server or if it's enabled (as in RewriteEngine is set to ON) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ...
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on the previous answer:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteLog "/absolute/path/to/your/wwwroot/public_html/rewrite.log"
  RewriteLogLevel 5
</IfModule>
```

If rewrite is on it'll log any rewrites that one may have. But it should be turned off as it is expensive on the server and wouldn't be ideal for a heavy production server.

Also, i can run: `httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES` to see what modules are running for apache.